# AngularJS - Check if selected date is equal to next business date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to check if selected date is equal to next business date using AngularJS. If selected date is not equal to the next business date, a warning will be shown, like twitter bootstrap's alert-warning, using ng-show angularjs directive.

Here's the current [**Fiddle**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Uk8cqQ?p=preview) for this.

Currently, the next business day is returned by getNextBusinessDay() $scope function. The comparison is triggered by ng-changed="comparisonResult()" which should return true/false based on comparison, but isn't working.

**Here my html code:**

```
<body ng-app="angularjs-starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div class="container">
  <section id="datepicker">
    <div class="bs-docs-example">
      <form class="form-horizontal well">
        <div class="control-group input-append">
          <label for="inputDatepicker" class="label" style="margin-right:6px;">
            Selected Date</label>
          <input id="inputDatepicker" class="input-small" type="text" 
            ng-model="selectedDate" ng-changed="comparisonResult()" 
            data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" bs-datepicker>
          <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="datepicker">
          <i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
</body>
```

**Here's my js code:**

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', ['$strap.directives']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $window, $location) {

  // Datepicker directive
  $scope.selectedDate = null;

    $scope.getNextBusinessDay = function() {
        return $scope.getDeliveryDateObj(1);
    }

    $scope.getDeliveryDateObj = function(businessDaysLeftForDelivery){
        var now = new Date();
        var dayOfTheWeek = now.getDay();
        var calendarDays = businessDaysLeftForDelivery;
        var deliveryDay = dayOfTheWeek + businessDaysLeftForDelivery;
        if (deliveryDay >= 6) {
            businessDaysLeftForDelivery -= 6 - dayOfTheWeek; // deduct this-week days
            calendarDays += 2; // count this coming weekend
            deliveryWeeks = Math.floor(businessDaysLeftForDelivery / 5); // how many whole weeks?
            calendarDays += deliveryWeeks * 2; // two days per weekend per week
        }
        now.setTime(now.getTime() + calendarDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

        now.setUTCHours(0);
        now.setUTCMinutes(0);
        now.setUTCSeconds(0);
        now.setUTCMilliseconds(0);

        return now;
    }

    $scope.getNextBusinessDay();

    $scope.comparisonResult = function() {
        if($scope.selectedDate == $scope.getNextBusinessDay()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    };

});
```

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When comparing dates, use `a.getTime() == b.getTime()` instead of `a == b`.

Answer (score 0):

It is 2017 now, if you use Angular >= v1.2 you can use angular.equals(date1, date2)